# CakePHP 2.0 css and scripts in element not being added to css/script blocks

Tags: view, element, block, cakephp-2.0, fetch

I have just started a project with cakePHP 2.0. I am using an element to render a sidebar menu. I would like to specify the css and JS files for the menu in the menu element and not add them in my head tag (in case I'd like to conditionally render different sidebars).
For some reason my scripts and CSS are not being output.. any ideas why?

**Layouts/Default.ctp**

```
<head>
<?php
echo $this->fetch('css');
echo $this->fetch('script');
?>
</head>
....
<div id="leftcolumn">
<?php  echo $this->element('sidebar/menu'); ?>
</div>
```

Elements/sidebar/menu.ctp

```
$this->Html->script('menu', array('inline' => false));
$this->Html->css('menu', null, array('inline' => false));
<div class="sidebarmenu"><ul><li>Menu Item</li></ul></div>
```

CSS and javascript are in webroot/css/menu.css and webroot/js/menu.js respectively.

If I put the Html->script and Html->css declarations in a view file or home.ctp or default.ctp they get added to the css and script blocks and are output just fine. When they are declared in the element file menu.ctp they don't work. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

```
// css
$this->start('css');
echo $this->Html->css('additionalstyle');
echo $this->Html->css('anotherstyle');
echo $this->end()

// javascript
$this->start('script')
echo $this->Html->script('jquery');
$this->end()
```

Add this code in your view.ctp

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $this->Html->script('menu', array('inline' => false));
echo $this->Html->css('menu', null, array('inline' => false));
```

I think I got the problems. Main Problem is the order of css and js calling.

```
echo $this->fetch('css');
echo $this->fetch('script');
```

This two lines are echoing within head i.e. before calling you element. So there are two possible solutions for this issue:

1. cut above `fetch()` from head and append it before end of body tag so that it load scripts and css after all DOM available. i.e.

   ...
     ...
     echo $this->fetch('css');
     echo $this->fetch('script');
2. make `"inline" => true` i.e.

   ```
   echo $this->Html->script('myel', array('inline' => true));
   echo $this->Html->css('mycss', null, array('inline' => true));
   ```

I think this will solve your problems....

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried adding echo and it doesn't seem to have helped... any other ideas?